# Gradle can't resolve 'kotlin' plugin. Am I missing the correct maven repository?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

`gradle tasks` fails telling me it can't find the plugin 'kotlin'. My `build.gradle` file starts with:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/" }
    maven { url "http://central.maven.org/maven2/" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

plugins {
  id 'kotlin'
  id 'application'
}
```

WRT maven repositories, I'm clearly just trying to redundantly add all the kitchen sinks I can find. I have tried none, and commenting out some. Which one am I missing?
From the log:

```
12:55:04.419 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult] Daemon is dispatching the build result: Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.Repor
tedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file '/home/_/workspace/_/build.gradle' line: 18
Plugin [id: 'kotlin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (not a core plugin, please see https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/standard_plugins.html for available core plugins)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)]
```

I have also tried version 1.3.10 because it matches what's listed in gradle version info:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Linux 4.19.6-200.fc28.x86_64 amd64
```

Comment: There is no plugin with ID "kotlin". Here's the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Kotlin* is not a core plugin, therefore you have to include the version. Also the name is different, when using the `plugins` configuration:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.11"
}
```

If you use the `apply` function, you could still use the simple name:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin"
```

You'll find this information on [Targeting the JVM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-the-jvm).

Comment: The `id` line fails with: "argument list must be exactly 1 literal non empty string"
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/I39ips1wsE3dkQMdTdrhAA

Comment: You cannot use variables there. The version must be a constant and literal string. No other statements are allowed; their presence will cause a compilation error. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:constrained_syntax